# Call ReSharper ContextAction from Action

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-6.1, resharper-plugins

I want to write a ReSharper `Action` that just calls a `ContextAction`. Is this possible? <strike>A `ContextAction` takes a `Solution` as a parameter, and an `Action` gets a `DataContext` on construction. So the question really becomes:</strike>

Can you get the current `Solution` from an instance of `DataContext`?

EDIT: Oops! I asked the wrong thing. The above is true, but not the real problem.  Like Dmitri below says, you can get indeed the solution like so:

```
var solution = 
  dataContext.GetData(JetBrains.ProjectModel.DataContext.DataConstants.SOLUTION);
```

The tricky bit is getting the `_psiModule`, which can be gotten from the `ICSharpContextDataProvider` which is passed in when the `ContextAction` is constructed, via `provider.PsiModule`. Can you get an `ICSharpContextDataProvider` or the correct `PsiModule` from the `DataContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var document = context.GetData(DocumentModel.DataConstants.DOCUMENT);
  var solution = context.GetData(JetBrains.ProjectModel.DataContext.DataConstants.SOLUTION);
  var psiModule = document.GetPsiSourceFile(solution).GetPsiModule();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the solution like so:

```
var solution =
  dataContext.GetData(JetBrains.ProjectModel.DataContext.DataConstants.SOLUTION)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I made a mistake. The really difficult part is getting the `PsiModule`. I don't even know if it's possible, but I hope so. Thanks for all your help with the ReSharper questions I've been asking, by the way. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Take a look at what `dataContext` has in it - just set a breakpoint and peek at what it contains. The contents are largely dependant on where you are when this is called. You might have, say, a type declaration, and you can take the PSI Module from that.